# ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'table.column' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, typescript, express

i'm getting a really confused problem... i'm triying to do a query:

```
SELECT ordenes_servicio.idorden, estatus_orden.descripcion AS estatus, tipo_orden.descripcion AS tipo_orden, usuario.nombre, ordenes_servicio.nombres_cliente, ordenes_servicio.fecha_asig 
FROM ordenes_servicio 
INNER JOIN estatus_orden ON ordenes_servicio.idestatus_orden = estatus_orden.idestatus_orden 
INNER JOIN tipo_orden ON ordenes_servicio.idtipo_orden = tipo_orden.idtipo_orden 
INNER JOIN usuario ON ordenes_servicio.id = usuario.id 
ORDER BY ordenes_servicio.idorden DESC
```

The problem is that when i try to run it, it say

> ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'ordenes_servicio.idusuario' in
>   'on clause'

But if you look at the query, there is no 'ordenes_servicio.idusuario', and yes there was, but i update my tables, both of them, and it is like the query is still triying to get that column.

When i execute the query in my MySQL Workbench it work, but dont when i try to run it in my application... Someone can help me? :/

Note: my "app" is actually a REST API in typescript, and i'm using express library

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer... if can help a beginner like me someday. Im actually executing three querys, and there was one of then that still had "ordenes_servicio.idusuario"... that's all.. So check your querys!

Beginner error...